# Image preview doesn't work in ranger

Tags: w3m

I have installed ranger file manager and rxvt-unicode terminal, and I want ranger to display previews of images in the terminal. I have also installed w3m, but I can't get images to preview. I think this is an issue for w3m, because when I load webpages with w3m, no images appear.

edit: w3m will now display images when i load webpages and images, but ranger does not preview....

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS x86_64
I think I need to get urxvt with pixbuf support, but I have no idea how to get that. I have tried searching to find out how to get urxvt with pixbuf support, but only results for arch etc. is available it seem like.

Comment: What version Ubuntu is this?

Comment: I am running 18.04 (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS x86_64)

Answer (score 12):

### TL;DR

1. On the default Ubuntu terminal I installed `ueberzug` with: `pip3 install  ueberzug`
2. On rangers configurations at ~/.config/ranger/rc.conf I added( or edited already existing) these two lines :

```
set preview_images true
set preview_images_method  ueberzug
```

3. Worked like a charm(and it will work on any other terminal as well)

### My other trials

I just had the same experience as you and I couldn't make it work but I have a few notes on your trial and a pretty easy alternative that actually worked

First thing first w3m package of ubuntu doesn't contain image preview so you need to explicitly type `sudo apt install w3m-img` then you need to locate it on the path at a place like `/usr/lib/w3m/w3mimagedisplay` and add it to your path .Though this installation of w3mimagedisplay seems broken to me you might have better luck.Also kitty as suggested by the other answer worked for me , though  I didn't have time to change my default terminal as I have  a lot of configurations on it. So I count these solution more "lightweight" as it just needs one python script to run. Even though kitty is a handy terminal and many people might prefer it.

### Update 1 December 2022

This solution is not suggested anymore as it is quite difficult to install `ueberzug` now that the project is not under active development.

#### But..

If one insists on using this method you can build ueberzug manually with:

```sh
sudo apt install libxext-dev libx11-dev -y
git clone --depth 1 --branch 18.1.9 https://github.com/seebye/ueberzug.git
cd ueberzug
python3 setup.py install
```

Comment: first part worked like a charm in manjaro xfce with `xfce4-terminal`.

Comment: The ueberzug project has been archived by the developer. `pip3 install ueberzug` doesn't work anymore.
https://github.com/seebye/ueberzug

Comment: @Guillaume
As I have the most liked answer now I feel like I have to find another easy solution, I'll come back

Comment: I had to `sudo apt install libxext-dev libx11-dev -y` for this to install properly on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @Dave I will add those to my answer, and I will wait for other people to report missing dependencies

Answer (score 10):

Ranger does not have image previewing enabled by default. You need to enable it in its configuration file.

First, in case you do not already have a user-specific config file, create one by copying the default config file:

```
mkdir -pv ~/.config/ranger/
cp -vi /usr/share/doc/ranger/config/rc.conf ~/.config/ranger/rc.conf
```

Then open `~/.config/ranger/rc.conf` using your favorite text editor.

To enable image previews, find the `preview_images` option and change it to `true`. i.e. the line would read:

```
set preview_images true
```

Then, find the option `preview_images_method`, and set it according to your terminal to one of the values enumerated and explained in the comment block preceding it. In your case, it's `urxvt`. So the line should read:

```
set preview_images_method urxvt
```

After that, quit ranger and start it again for the new configuration to take effect.

If all fails, I personally use it with the Kitty terminal and it works. If you want to try it out, first install Kitty, change the aforementioned `preview_images_method` option to `kitty`, then launch kitty and start ranger in it.

Comment: Adding this part, 'set preview_images_method urxvt' fixed an issue for me where a black line would be drawn through the image when changing focus to a new screen (using Awesome WM on my setup). Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and I managed to use image preview with **ranger** and **foot** terminal.

First I installed *sixel*:

```
sudo apt install libsixel-bin libsixel-dev libsixel1
```

Sixel requires a recent *ranger*, so I removed the package and I downloaded and installed the latest from source:

```
sudo apt remove ranger
git clone https://github.com/ranger/ranger.git
cd ranger
sudo make install
```

If you have not already done, copy the default *ranger* config:

```
mkdir -pv ~/.config/ranger/
cp -vni /usr/local/share/doc/ranger/config/rc.conf ~/.config/ranger/rc.conf
```

I enabled image preview as some other answers correctly stated in ~/.config/ranger/rc.conf:

```
set preview_images true
```

Then I configured it to preview with *sixel*

```
set preview_images_method sixel
```

Now start *ranger* and it will correctly render image previews.